FFT nyquist frequency
I faced a problem with the fft in scipy and I'd like to explain this using an example.
First I create a random signal with N=10 datapoints:
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft
random_signal = np.random.rand(10)

print(random_signal) gives:
array([0.51980334, 0.42128469, 0.20434206, 0.89675551, 0.46041547,
   0.43427306, 0.53322509, 0.8649269 , 0.40062739, 0.81627666])

Conducting the fft
fft_result = fft(random_signal)

and printing the results
print(fft_result[0])
print(fft_result[1])
print(fft_result[2])
print(fft_result[3])
print(fft_result[4])
print(fft_result[5])
print(fft_result[6])
print(fft_result[7])
print(fft_result[8])
print(fft_result[9])

leads to
(5.55193017189147-0j)
(-0.0745776159990815+0.4313745073898074j)
(-0.27110587637589284+0.44049563159973254j)
(0.9459550630790063+0.3482405244581592j)
(-0.11966821916389306-0.027575211471326383j)
(-1.3151034689371879-0j)
(-0.11966821916389306+0.027575211471326383j)
(0.9459550630790063-0.3482405244581592j)
(-0.27110587637589284-0.44049563159973254j)
(-0.0745776159990815-0.4313745073898074j)

The first value fft_result[0] corresponds to the mean of the input signal, also called the DC component.
What I do now is to take only the fft values from 0 to N//2-1 or fft_result[0:N/2], since fft_result[5] is the value at Nyquist frequency and useless.
Regarding my problem: I end up with the first half (left-hand side) of the fft_result and I'd like to conduct an iFFT. I can reconstruct the right-hand side of the signal but I don't have the value at the nyquist frequency fft_result[5] anymore.
How can I compute this value or should I just replace the value with a zero? My goal is to reconstruct the fft output to conduct the iFFT getting the original time signal back. Does the value at nyquist influence the iFFT output?

Why do you assume the midpoint corresponds to the Nyquist frequency?  I believe all the values are significant and you'll need them all for the iFFT.

Since the input is real-valued and the information beyond the nyquist are redudant: Those are the complex conjugate of them as you can see in the example.

I'm sure you're correct that anything beyond Nyquist would be worthless.  What I want to know is why you think the FFT contains anything beyond Nyquist?

“since fft_result[5] is the value at Nyquist frequency and useless.” — “but I don't have the value at the nyquist frequency fft_result[5] anymore.” I mean, the answer here writes itself… You came to the right convolution on your own, you just weren’t willing to accept it?

@CrisLuengo Sure, I thought maybe there were another way to compute the missing value at nyquist, as it is for example for the DC component which is the mean of the input signal. I would like to ask this question here, since I didn't find anything regarding this question. People just throw away the value at Nyquist and never mention that you are loosing information being not able to recreate the input signal.

Some explanations: A signal at the Nyquist frequency aliases onto itself. That means that this frequency component is not sampled correctly, it is aliased, and cannot be reconstructed correctly (we don't know its true phase or amplitude). So, ideally, you'd have to remove that frequency component before sampling. But once your signal is sampled, you cannot undo any aliasing that was already done. An image where pixels in a row alternate black and white are at this frequency. Removing that frequency component will erase that pattern from the image.

Yes, you will need to keep the Nyquist frequency value if you want to correctly invert the FFT. So that you don't have to do the truncation of the FFT output yourself, you could instead use rfft and invert using irfft.

Thank you for the answer. If n is even, the length of the transformed axis is (n/2)+1 is what rfft is doing. So the nyquist value is stored.
